# Please help me to explain why past continuous tense is used in that case

Tags: past-tense

A : Do you bring your lunch today ?
B : No, I was thinking about going out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, A would say *Did you bring* or *Have you brought your lunch?*. The action of arriving (at work?) with a packed lunch happened earlier.

The thought *I will go out for lunch today* was in B's mind earlier too, at the time they decided not to prepare a packed lunch. B might have said *I thought I would go out for lunch*, but the continuous tense is just a way of indicating that the thought was in their mind for some time.